# Using '*' in the data indicating ignoring condition

Tags: oracle

My code 1 below shows the result as expected.
My goal is to use '*' to indicate ignoring condition-in this case "cat like 'col2' associated with corresponding column.
So the desired result of my code 2 is as below. How to modify my code 2 to get desired result?

My code 1

```
with a as (  
    select 'a____' col1, 'c__' col2  from dual  
    union all  
    select 'a____', 'd__' from dual  
)  
select * from a 
where 'apple' like col1 and 'cat' like col2;
```

result

```
COL1  COL2
----   -----
a____    c__
```

My code 2

```
with a as (  
    select 'a____' col1, 'c__' col2  from dual  
    union all  
    select 'a____', '*' from dual  --Data have '*' to indicate ignoring condition
)  
select * from a 
where 'apple' like col1 and 'cat' like col2; --"How to modify here to get desired output?"
```

Desired result

```
col1    col2
------   -------
a____    c__
a____    *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve it using OR condition for both col1 and col2 as follows:

```
SQL> with a as (
  2      select 'a____' col1, 'c__' col2  from dual
  3      union all
  4      select 'a____', '*' from dual  --Data have '*' to indicate ignoring condition
  5  )
  6  select * from a
  7  where ('apple' like col1 or col2 = '*') -- see this
  8    and ('cat' like col2 or col2 = '*'); -- see this

COL1            COL2
--------------- --------------------
a____           c__
a____           *

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

In oracle, you need to use `%` instead of `*`.
The following will work the desired way.

```
 with a as (  
    select 'a____' col1, 'c__' col2  from dual  
            union all  
            select 'a____', '%' from dual  --Data have '*' to indicate ignoring condition
    )  
    select * from a 
    where 'apple' like col1 and 'cat' like col2;
```

returns

```
col1    col2
------   -------
a____    c__
a____    % <-- not your desired asterisk, but I guess you want to see the match here
```

See also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm:

> - An underscore (_) in the pattern matches exactly one character (as    opposed to one byte in a multibyte character set) in the value.
> - A percent sign (%) in the pattern can match zero or more characters (as opposed to bytes in a multibyte character set) in the    value.
>     The pattern '%' cannot match a null.